# Include order count from custom order status in WooCommerce admin menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I have added a custom order status using this code in `functions.php`

```php
// Register new order status
function register_produktionsklar_order_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-produktionsklar', array(
        'label'                     => 'Klar til produktion',
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Klar til produktion (%s)', 'Klar til produktion (%s)' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_produktionsklar_order_status' );

// Add new order status to list of WC Order statuses
function add_produktionsklar_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {

    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {

        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;

        if ( 'wc-afventer-godkend' === $key ) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-produktionsklar'] = 'Klar til produktion';
        }
    }

    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_produktionsklar_to_order_statuses' );
```

---

I would like to include this custom order status in the order count. When I change the status to this custom status, the order is no longer counted in the open orders number. (see attached image for clarity)

[image]

Any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default only orders with the status 'processing' are counted and added to the orders count number.

To adjust this we are going to use the `woocommerce_menu_order_count` filter hook and `wc_orders_count()` function, which return the orders count of a specific order status.

So you get:

```php
/**
 * Add orders count of a specific order status
 */
function filter_woocommerce_menu_order_count( $wc_processing_order_count ) {
    // Call function and pass custom order status
    $order_count_produktionsklar = wc_orders_count( 'produktionsklar' );
    
    return $wc_processing_order_count + $order_count_produktionsklar;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_menu_order_count', 'filter_woocommerce_menu_order_count', 10, 1 );
```

---

I also have rewritten your code with this updated code. For example, the `init` hook has been replaced with `woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses` to register custom order statuses.

```php
/**
 * Register order status
 */
function filter_woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    // Status must start with "wc-"
    $order_statuses['wc-produktionsklar'] = array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Klar til produktion', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => false,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        /* translators: %s: number of orders */
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Klar til produktion <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Klar til produktion <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' ),       
    );
    
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses', 'filter_woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Show order status in the dropdown @ single order
 */
function filter_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {  
    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // Add new order status after processing
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {

        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;

        if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
            // Status must start with "wc-"
            $new_order_statuses['wc-produktionsklar'] = _x( 'Klar til produktion', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }

    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'filter_wc_order_statuses', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Show order status in the dropdown @ bulk actions
 */
function filter_bulk_actions_edit_shop_order( $bulk_actions ) {
    // Note: "mark_" must be there instead of "wc"
    $bulk_actions['mark_produktionsklar'] = __( 'Klar til produktion', 'woocommerce' );
    return $bulk_actions;
}
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'filter_bulk_actions_edit_shop_order', 10, 1 );
```