# Do multiple actions on bulk action in Woocommerce orders list

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website where I use plugin for GLS export parcel service. When I run bulk action Export My GLS it generates printing delivery tickets for each marked order and exports it as PDF.

 The problem is that when I select over 30 orders and If I dont remember which ones I've marked during the bulk action I dont see any information about this order was exported (only at MYGLS dashboard, but it takes so much time). So I have created a custom order status called GLS exported and I need to change the marked woocommerce order status for each marked order when bulk action Export MYGLS finishs its process and refresh the page with the PDF export. I've searched all over the internet to find a solution tu run multiple bulk actions at once but I did not find anything which helped me in this case.

My custom order status code is bellow:

```
 function wc_register_post_statuses() {
register_post_status( 'wc-gls', array(
    'label'                     => 'GLS exported',
    'public'                    => true,
    'exclude_from_search'       => false,
    'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
    'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'GLS exported <span class="count"> 
    (%s)</span>', 'GLS exported <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
));
}
add_filter( 'init', 'wc_register_post_statuses' );

function wc_add_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
   $order_statuses['wc-gls'] = 
   _x( 'GLS exported', 'Order Status', '' );
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wc_add_order_statuses', 10, 1 );
```

In the plugin files I found this js code which adds the bulk action into select menu. But this bulk action is made of many code because its directly connected into API of the GLS parcel service.
Plugin URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/invelity-mygls-connect/

```
/**
     * Adds option to export invoices to orders page bulk select
     */
    function custom_bulk_admin_footer()
    {
        global $post_type;

        if ($post_type == 'shop_order') {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                    jQuery('<option>').val('my_gls').text('<?php _e('Export MyGLS')?>').appendTo("select[name='action']");
                    jQuery('<option>').val('my_gls').text('<?php _e('Export MyGLS')?>').appendTo("select[name='action2']");
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

Do you have any idea how could I add the extra function to change the order status to **GLS exported** when **Export MYGLS** bulk action is about to run?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I have reread your question several times but do not fully understand it. Maybe it's because I don't use the GLS plugin. Can you clarify your question with some screenshots? PS to register a custom order status, use the `woocommerce_register_shop_order_post_statuses` filter hook versus `init`, see the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68066373/11987538)

Comment: Hello @7uc1f3r in woocommerce order list as you have bulk actions like mark order as completed etc. I have extra bulk action from GLS plugin which is called export MYGLS. This bulk action generates shipping tickets which you print and paste it to the package. Its directly connected with API key to GLS. I need also change woocommerce order status when I run bulk action Export MYGLS of marked orders for which Ive generated the prints shipping tickets so I will know that these orders are ready for export.

Comment: **1/2** Normally adding a custom order status (bulk action) is done via `bulk_actions-edit-shop_order` hook and the callback for the bulk action could then be overwritten via `handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order`. However, as you indicated in your question, the bulk action was not added via a hook but via jQuery, the callback action is received by `load-edit.php`. In short, the plugin you are using deviates from the standard guidelines which basically means your question is really asking for customizations that not only apply in WooCommerce but also in the plugin you're using. Since there...

Comment: **2/2** ...are probably very few other users here on Stack Overflow who also use that plugin, your question may be considered as too broad. Regards