# Add custom order status count to admin WooCommerce menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

Based on that article [Include order count from custom order status in WooCommerce admin menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68057376/include-order-count-from-custom-order-status-in-woocommerce-admin-menu), I know that we can adjust the count from the WooCommerce default "in processing" orders count. We want to add a second count for orders in a special status "shipped". I don't find a way to add this second count in that area.

```
// Add orders count of a specific order status
function filter_woocommerce_menu_order_count( $wc_processing_order_count ) {
    // Call function and pass custom order status
    $order_count_shipped = wc_orders_count( 'shipped' );
    
    return $wc_processing_order_count + $order_count_shipped;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_menu_order_count', 'filter_woocommerce_menu_order_count', 10, 1 );
```

Does someone know how I can add there such a count in blue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done easily with the following function, based on [`menu_order_count()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/7.8/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-menus.php#L195-L219) WooCommerce core function hooked in 'admin_menu' action hook.

The code that will add a 2nd count *(in blue)* for "shipped" *(custom status)* orders:

```php
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'menu_order_count2', 20  );
function menu_order_count2() {
    global $submenu;

    if ( isset( $submenu['woocommerce'] ) ) {
        // Add count if user has access.
        if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_include_processing_order_count_in_menu', true ) && current_user_can( 'edit_others_shop_orders' ) ) {
            $custom_status = 'completed'; // <= Here set your custom status
            $order_count = wc_orders_count( $custom_status );

            if ( $order_count ) {
                foreach ( $submenu['woocommerce'] as $key => $menu_item ) {
                    if ( 0 === strpos( $menu_item[0], _x( 'Orders', 'Admin menu name', 'woocommerce' ) ) ) {
                        $submenu['woocommerce'][ $key ][0] .= sprintf(
                            ' <span class="%s" style="%s"><span class="%s-count">%s</span></span>',
                            'awaiting-mod update-plugins count-'. esc_attr( $order_count ),
                            'background-color:#007fe5', $custom_status, number_format_i18n( $order_count )
                        );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

You will get:

[image]